# Use Github to clone another branch from a remote repo into my clone of that repo

Tags: git, github

I have been a contributor to a project XYZ for a while. I have cloned the `main` branch of the XYZ repo to my Github account, and make edits and PRs to contribute back. (I don't have write access to the XYZ repo.)

Someone created a new branch `new-branch` of the XYZ repo. How can I clone/pull/get that branch into my repo? I have not yet found a way to do this through the Github web GUI. Many thanks